# preg_match_all how to find specify only <p> tags that end with <br></p>

Tags: php, regex, html-parsing

I have been playing around with this and I am left with this...

```
preg_match_all('/<p>(.*?)<br>(.*?)<p>/s', $offices, $district);
```

Which is working OK... but there is of course one record causing problems. How can I specify and get all the text within `<p>` tags that have `<br>` in them? Preferably specifying more that one `<br>` within the `<p>` and excluding the Eddy Lite tag?

The string is an address, such as:

```
    <h3>District Offices:</h3>
<p>
317 Dun Avenue<br>Suite 17<br>Port Samson, AK 32675<br>
(XXX) XXX-XXXX<br> 
VOIP: 40800<br> 
FAX (888) xxx-38xx<br> 

</p>

<h4>Staff Assistants:</h4>
<p>Beth Booger and Ly Sweet</p>

<h4>Secretary:</h4>
<p>Eddy Lite </p>

<p>
OK City Hall<br>110 S.E. Five Avenue<br>3rd Floor<br>Corpse, AK 33371<br>
(xxx) 694-xxxx<br> 

</p>

<h4>Staff Assistant:</h4>
<p>Con Sims </p>

    <br />

<h3>Home Office:</h3>
```

This is what I am getting back:
    Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] =>
    317 Dun Avenue
    Suite 17
    Port Samson, AK 32675
    (XXX) XXX-XXXX

```
Staff Assistants:

[1] =>

Eddy Lite 

OK City Hall
110 S.E. Five Avenue
3rd Floor
Corpse, AK 33371
(xxx) 694-xxxx
Staff Assistant:

) )
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
      I have tried:
      preg_match_all('/

(.*?)

/s', $offices, $district);
      preg_match_all('/

(.*)

/s', $offices, $district);
      preg_match_all('/

(.*?)
(.*?)

/', $offices, $district);
      preg_match_all('/

(.*?)
(.*?)
(.*?)

/s', $offices, $district);
      preg_match_all('/

(.*?)
(.*)
(.*)

/s', $offices, $district);

Comment: What are you trying to do specifically?

Comment: would not it easier if you are using php domdocument ?

Comment: **Don't use regular expressions to parse HTML**. You cannot reliably parse HTML with regular expressions. As soon as the HTML changes from your expectations, your code will be broken. See http://htmlparsing.com/php.html for examples of how to properly parse HTML with PHP modules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple workaround would be only allowing plain text and `<br>` tags:

```
preg_match_all('#<p>([^<>]*<br\s*/?>[^<>]*)+</p>#s', $offices, $district);
```

The usual note: such a regex only works for coherent and well-known input.

Comment: Thank you!  Works like a charm.  Normally I would use DOM but this is a special case.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
'~<p>(?=((?!</p>).)*<br>)((?!Eddy Lite).)*?</p>~s'
```